# Adding SpecFlow to existing .Net 5.0 project nets RhinoMocks version error

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow

I am adding SpecFlow to a C# project that has target net5.0, I get an error while trying to install SpecFlow 3.9.74 that should have .net 5 support starting in version 3.5.5, As best as I can see it's a dependency that's having an issue.

```
Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'RhinoMocks 3.6.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.  DSA.Automation.Core C:\Users\******Automation.Core.csproj   1
```

the csproj file has the following configs:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.9" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Playwright" Version="1.25.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit" Version="1.25.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.17.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Did you try updating the RhinoMocks NuGet package? That is the package mentioned in the error. Or just reinstall it.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I believe this package is installed and then removed in the process of installing dependencies, as when I search for this package in the installed tab, I don't see it.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of the Visual Studio project file (DSA.Automation.Core.csproj)?

Comment: It must be installed as a dependency of one of your project's NuGet packages. In Visual Studio, you should be able to expand the "Dependencies" --> "Packages" item in Solution Explorer. If I remember correctly, you can expand each NuGet package to see the packages it depends on. I wonder if you need to update any of them?